# use only variables to model an sqlite table with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm practicing in SQLite and Python. I'm trying to build a TABLE using only user prompts as database objects. After some extensive searches (official documentation says nothing about this kind of syntax-please correct me!) I found this method:

```
new_table = raw_input('Enter a table name: ')
column = raw_input('Enter column name: ')

cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tn} ({col})'''\
    .format(tn = new_table, col = column))
```

It works very nice and I find it intuitive. My problem is with INSERT INTO syntax. While the following code works ok:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({col}) VALUES (?)", ('goodmorning')\
    .format(tn=new_table, col=column))
```

This code below, won't work:

```
insdata = raw_input('Insert data for column: ')
cur.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({col}) VALUES (?)", (insdata,)\
    .format(tn=new_table, col=column))
```

and fails with error: 'tuple' object has no attribute format.

**Question is**: what is the proper syntax to assign *insdata* value to SQLite VALUES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write this is a slightly clearer fashion, you'll see what's going on:

```
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO {tn} ({col}) VALUES (?)", 
    (insdata,).format(tn=new_table, col=column)
 )
```

You're not formatting the string, you're formatting the a tuple of arguments.  Instead, you want:

```
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO {tn} ({col}) VALUES (?)".format(tn=new_table, col=column), 
    (insdata,)
 )
```

or perhaps a little more clearly :

```
 sql = "INSERT INTO {tn} ({col}) VALUES (?)".format(tn=new_table, col=column)
 cur.execute(sql, (insdata,))
```

In this case your line continuation character is not needed at all (since you're inside a function call) but if it were needed it would make much more sense to position it between arguments rather than between an object and the method invocation on the object.

Comment: god, I was formatting the tuple... Out of curiosity, is there any other way instead of using variables in curly brackets? If not, where is the above syntax/method documented? How one could have learned this formatting method of assigning variable names to db tables and columns? And of course, THANK you very much for such a timely and coherent reply!

Comment: @ToucHDowN It's not specific to databases, it's the general string formatting syntax. Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Beware that doing anything in databases with untrusted user input can be dangerous.

Comment: @glibdud thank you very much for the reference. I have studied some basic str methods up to now (.strip/split, etc) but haven't even touched the .format so the above SQL statement with the curly braces seemed alien to me. All clear now ... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are invoking format method of tuple (which appears not to have one) instead of a string with SQL query:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({col}) VALUES ({val})".format(tn=new_table,col=column,val='goodmorning'))
```